# How to determine Omni-Channel Agent Status in APEX?

Tags: apex, liveagent, omnichannel

Is there a reliable way to get an Agent's current Omni-Channel presence status using APEX?

The UserServicePresence table records *some* status changes, but notably *offline* is not a status change that gets stored there.

Incidentally, the code will need to execute in a trigger context, so I don't think there is a way to make use of the Console Toolkit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UserServicePresence is the right place to look. Offline is simply the absence of a status. If there are no UserServicePresence records where IsCurrentState==true, the user is in an offline state.

Comment: Funny thing, I just got this answer back from SFDC support. In fact, the comments appear to be a copy-paste from your answer and the follow-up date is after your answer was posted.