# Omni-channel: Automated Presence Status change

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, omnichannel

I've got a requirement which says that an Agent assigned to a Lead must have Presence Status set to 'busy' automatically when the right time comes: 10 minutes before the Date/Time field value in the Lead. Is there a way I could do that? I've been thinking about setting up a Schedulable class in order to update the status, but is it possible to access those settings via Apex?

Comment: checkout this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105793/how-to-determine-omni-channel-agent-status-in-apex

Comment: Yes, I've seen this one and while this solution works with quering, it doesnt't really work well with dml operations such as updating which is crucial for the whole logic. Thank you nevertheless